# jquery function stoped after unbind

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that gets executed to change my datepicker to get new values.  After I select my drop down 'changeme' it works.  The next time I try nothing happens?  I am not unbinding the changme drop down box.

```
 $("#changeme").change(function()
 {
    var d = newvalues();
    $("#sdate, #edate").removeClass("datepicker hasDatepicker");
    $("#sdate, #edate").unbind();
    $("#sdate, #edate").addClass("datepicker");

    $(".datepicker" ).datepicker({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", minDate:d.start_date,maxDate:d.stop_date, yearRange:d.start_year[0]+":"+d.stop_year[0]});
    submitform();
 }

function newvalues()
{
    var s_date = $("#changeme > :selected").data('start_date');
    var s_year = s_date.split("-");
    var st_date = $("#changeme > :selected").data('stop_date');
    var st_date = $("#changeme > :selected").data('stop_date');
    return {start_date:s_date,
    start_year:s_year, stop_year:st_year,stop_date:st_date
    };
}
```

*************** update *********************

Sorry my `$("#sdate").change(function(){submitform();});` stops working.

```
 $("#startdate").change(function()
    submitform();
 });
```

All it does is submits the form with new values. I will try to post a working copy.  But I am getting no errors. 
Once the page loads or you select run and you type into the  first text box it works.  Once you select an option from the drop down menu and try to update the text box.  the change function doesn't fire.
Here is a link to a fiddle.
[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pythondev1/oo6ughb3/)

Comment: No error in the console ?

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: You need to post your HTML on this one. I suspect you are reusing the same ID's on multiple elements. Otherwise, at the very least, you have a lot of redundant /jQuery code.

Comment: add relevant HTML for your script

Comment: Calling datepicker on the element more than once seems like a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  changed how i was using jquery a bit. I ended up removing the unbind and adding `$dateField.datepicker("option", {changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", minDate:d.start_date,maxDate:d.stop_date, yearRange:d.start_year[0]+":"+d.stop_year[0]});`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajcjk39r/)